# youtube player stops with an error that a library is required message

Tags: android

I wrote an application in android studio in which I use the youtubeplayer api, when I download the apk file to a xiaomi phone, the youtube player stops with an error saying that an error occurred during the initialization of the player, it gives a client library update required message.

When using android studio emulator the player works fine
I use android studio, Flamingo version, on PC
it's also interesting that it worked on the phone for two days

Comment: did any of the answers below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this happening is because on the phone you have a recently updated Youtube App installed and this blocks the initialization of the Youtube library.

I expecting you're using [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player) deprecated Youtube Android player.

As a possible solution, you can use [another](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) player that is based on IFrame Player API.

Answer (score 1):

If an Android device updates the youtube app then the old https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player library is stopped working. We can use https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference library for Development else uninstall the update of the youtube app and try it will work with the existing library.